# Create a POST API call within Shopify theme Liquid file

Tags: curl, post, shopify

On our Shopify website, in the footer, we have a submit button, for a newsletter form, where the customer can put down his phone number and email.

The code for the Newsletter portion looks like this

```
{% form 'customer', id: unique, data-newsletter-form: '', class: class %}
<input type="hidden" name="contact[tags]" value="newsletter">
<input type="hidden" name="contact[accepts_marketing]" value="true">
<div class="input-group input-group--inner-button float__wrapper">
  <label for="mail-{{ unique }}">{{ 'general.newsletter_form.email' | t }}</label>
  <input class="input-group-field" 
         type="email" 
         placeholder="{{ 'general.newsletter_form.newsletter_email' | t }}" 
         id="mail-{{ unique }}" 
         aria-label="{{ 'general.newsletter_form.newsletter_email' | t }}" 
         autocorrect="off" 
         autocapitalize="off" 
         name="contact[email]"
         data-newsletter-field 
         required/>

</div>

<div class="input-group input-group--inner-button float__wrapper">
  <label for="phone-{{ unique }}">PHONE</label>
  <input class="input-group-field" 
         type="tel" 
         name="phone"
         pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
         placeholder="123-456-7890" 
         id="phone-{{ unique }}" 
         aria-label="Enter your phone number" 
         name="contact[phone]"
         data-newsletter-field
         />

</div>
<button 
        type="submit" {% unless show_icon %}class="{{ style }} {{ color }} uppercase"{% endunless %} 
        aria-label="{{ text }}"
        name="subscribe" 
        id="subscribe-{{ unique }}"
        onclick="addUser()"
  >
</button>
{% endform %}
```

One of the first changes I made, was to the button I added an OnClick function,

```
onclick="addUser()"
```

Then on the bottom, I added this code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function addUser(){ 
   
  }
</script>
```

Which will allow me to define the addUser function.

Now, I'm not sure about this part, but after trying to do a lot of self studying, I think the next correct step would be to make the addUser() function look something like this

```
 function addUser(){ 

  fetch('https://api.attentivemobile.com/v1/subscriptions', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer <YOUR_TOKEN_HERE>',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          'user': {
              'phone': '+13115552368',
              'email': 'test@gmail.com'
          },
          'signUpSourceId': 'string',
      })
  });   
   
  }
```

Am I moving in the right direction?

What I used to create that code was the documentation that the app I'm trying to integrate sent me

https://docs.attentivemobile.com/openapi/reference/tag/Subscribers/

On the right hand side, they have payload and curl samples, and I used an online tool that helped me convert it to the JS function.

The signupsourceID was provided by Attentive Support so I have that. I am assuming I will also have to ask them for the Bearer Auth Token.

My question is, how I can take the email and phone from the form when they submit, and add it to the fetch call?

I am assuming I can pass the variables to my AddUser() function, but I'm not sure how to do that in Shopify liquid code.

I have a programming background, but very little in Javascript, CSS, or Shopify Liquid. I was assigned this task and have been trying to figure out how to program it in for close to the past 3 weeks.

I have slowly been making progress but I am still quite far behind. If anyone could help me or just provide some suggestions or advice, I would greatly appreciate it.

---

Here is the full code:

```
<!-- /snippets/newsletter-form.liquid -->

<h6> <a style = "color:blue; text-decoration: underline;" href="https://sprayground.attn.tv/p/a0h/landing-page">Stay in the Know! </a></h6> 
<br>

{% comment %}
{% render 'newsletter-form', unique: unique, text: block.settings.button_text, style: block.settings.button_style, color: block.settings.button_color %}
{% endcomment %}
{%- liquid 
  assign style = style | default: 'btn'
  assign color = color | default: 'btn--secondary'
  assign translation = 'general.newsletter_form.submit' | t 
  assign text = text | default: translation
  assign class = 'newsletter--default-messages'

  if success_text != blank
    assign class = ''
  endif  
-%}

{%- if unique -%}
{% form 'customer', id: unique, data-newsletter-form: '', class: class %}
{% if content != blank %}
{{ content }}
{% endif %}

{% if success_text != blank %}
<p class="newsletter__message newsletter__message--success">{{ success_text | newline_to_br }}</p>

<p class="newsletter__message newsletter__message--error"><em>{{ 'general.newsletter_form.error_message' | t }}</em></p>
{% else %}
{% if form.posted_successfully? %}
<p><em>{{ 'general.newsletter_form.subscribed' | t }}</em></p>
{% elsif form.errors %}
{% for field in form.errors %}
<p><em>{{ field }} - {{ form.errors.messages[field] }}</em></p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}

<input type="hidden" name="contact[tags]" value="newsletter">
<input type="hidden" name="contact[accepts_marketing]" value="true">
<div class="input-group input-group--inner-button float__wrapper">
  <label for="mail-{{ unique }}">{{ 'general.newsletter_form.email' | t }}</label>
  <input class="input-group-field" 
         type="email" 
         placeholder="{{ 'general.newsletter_form.newsletter_email' | t }}" 
         id="mail-{{ unique }}" 
         aria-label="{{ 'general.newsletter_form.newsletter_email' | t }}" 
         autocorrect="off" 
         autocapitalize="off" 
         name="contact[email]"
         data-newsletter-field 
         required/>

</div>

<div class="input-group input-group--inner-button float__wrapper">
  <label for="phone-{{ unique }}">PHONE</label>
  <input class="input-group-field" 
         type="tel" 
         name="phone"
         pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
         placeholder="123-456-7890" 
         id="phone-{{ unique }}" 
         aria-label="Enter your phone number" 
         name="contact[phone]"
         data-newsletter-field
         />

</div>
<button 
        type="submit" {% unless show_icon %}class="{{ style }} {{ color }} uppercase"{% endunless %} 
        aria-label="{{ text }}"
        name="subscribe" 
        id="subscribe-{{ unique }}"
        onclick="addUser()"
  >
  {%- if show_icon -%}
  {%- render 'icon-arrow-right-long' -%}
  {%- render 'icon-check-slim' -%}
  {%- else -%}  
  {{ text }}
  {%- endif -%}
</button>

<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
By submitting this form, you agree to receive recurring automated promotional and personalized marketing text messages (e.g. cart reminders) from Sprayground at the cell number used when signing up. Consent is not a condition of any purchase. Reply HELP for help and STOP to cancel. Msg frequency varies. Msg & data rates may apply. View Terms & Privacy 
</details>

  
{% endform %}
{%- endif -%}

<style>
  form#footer-newsletter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .input-group.input-group--inner-button.float__wrapper {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
  }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
 function addUser(){
 
  let phone = document.querySelector("input[name='contact[phone]']")
  let email = document.querySelector("input[name='contact[email]']")

  console.log("phone") 
  console.log(phone) 
  console.log("email") 
  console.log(email) 

  fetch('https://api.attentivemobile.com/v1/subscriptions', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer <YOUR_TOKEN_HERE>',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          'user': {
              'phone': phone.value,
              'email': email.value
          },
          'signUpSourceId': '123456',
      })
  });   
   
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple you can get the values from any selector using a JavaScript query selector.

```
 function addUser(){
 
  let phone = document.querySelector("input[name='contact[phone]']")
  let email = document.querySelector("input[name='contact[email]']")

  fetch('https://api.attentivemobile.com/v1/subscriptions', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer <YOUR_TOKEN_HERE>',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          'user': {
              'phone': phone.value,
              'email': email.value
          },
          'signUpSourceId': 'string',
      })
  });   
   
  }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for trying to help. I've been struggling with this problem for close to a month. I tried to implement your code and added some console log statements to test it. It doesn't seem to work and I am pretty sure I did something wrong.  So I pasted my full actual code at the bottom of my original question. Is it the onclick action and it should be something else because we are using Shopify forms? Thanks a lot.

Comment: change the button type="submit" to type="button" and check again.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. I've tried that. This is what my console shows now https://i.imgur.com/y7f8SVI.png   This is when I try to print phone.value and email.value. I also checked our attentive portal, it doesn't seem customers are being added.

Comment: your store link please I will check myself

Comment: sprayground.com

Comment: if you need the shopify link it's https://sprygrnd.myshopify.com/admin

Comment: hey sorry I don't mean to be a pain, but please let me know if you discovered anything

Comment: @user7959439 I will check no problem I was busy

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. It's funny just as you typed that, I was in a zoom with my boss about the issue. Btw, do you have Discord or anything like that by any chance? For easier communication

Comment: @user7959439 Yes I have discord hamzasgd#2989